# Why does it feel so cold after you step out of a hot shower?

Tags: temperature, everyday-life

Whenever I take a hot shower and close the shower curtain, it expectedly feels nice and warm. However, as soon as I open the curtain, I feel a rush of cold air instantly. I'm sure everybody has experienced this.

Why does this occur? Does it have something to do with the fact that warm air rises and so the cold air takes its place as soon as the shower curtain is opened?

Comment: This version is better than [the previous version](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/543966/why-does-it-feel-so-cold-when-you-slide-open-the-curtain-after-a-hot-shower), but you should have edited that one instead of asking a fresh question.

Comment: This is not a trivial question. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shower-curtain_effect

Comment: @PM2Ring Ah thanks for finding that